# Creating objects by function and using methods without storing the object within a variable

Tags: javascript, object, methods

is there a way for the function to create the objects without storing them in a variable let as shown in the following code:

```js
var createRiver = function(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {

  if (!(this instanceof createRiver)) {
    return new createRiver(name, continent, lengthInKilometers);
  }

  this.name = name;
  this.continent = continent;
  this.lengthInKilometers = lengthInKilometers;
}
let Amazon = createRiver('Amazon', 'South America', 6575) //Without let
let Danube = createRiver('Danube', 'Europe', 2850) //Without let


createRiver.prototype.isLongerThan = function(r) {
  if (this.lengthInKilometers > r.lengthInKilometers) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
Danube.isLongerThan(Amazon); //flase
Amazon.isLongerThan(Danube); //true 


createRiver.prototype.logRiver = function() {
  console.log("The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long.");
}


Amazon.logRiver(); ////The Amazon river is 6575 kilometers long.
```

Comment: Where do you want to store them instead? You can put them in an array.

Comment: this is unclear, you want to store information without storing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods diretly on the result of calling the constructor function.

```
createRiver('Amazon', 'South America', 6575).logRiver();

console.log(createRiver('Amazon', 'South America', 6575).isLongerThan(createRiver('Danube', 'Europe', 2850)));
```

But when you do this, the objects are discarded as soon as the method finishes, since there are no permanent references to them.

You can push them into an array.

```js
var createRiver = function(name, continent, lengthInKilometers) {

  if (!(this instanceof createRiver)) {
    return new createRiver(name, continent, lengthInKilometers);
  }

  this.name = name;
  this.continent = continent;
  this.lengthInKilometers = lengthInKilometers;
}

let arrayRiver = [];
arrayRiver.push(createRiver('Amazon', 'South America', 6575)); 
arrayRiver.push(createRiver('Danube', 'Europe', 2850));

console.log(arrayRiver);

createRiver.prototype.isLongerThan = function(r) {
  if (this.lengthInKilometers > r.lengthInKilometers) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Sort rivers by length
arrayRiver.sort((r1, r2) => r1.lengthInKilometers - r2.lengthInKilometers);

createRiver.prototype.logRiver = function() {
  console.log("The " + this.name + " river is " + this.lengthInKilometers + " kilometers long.");
}

// Log all rivers
arrayRiver.forEach(r => r.logRiver());
```

Comment: I mean, is there a way to execute the methods on the objects that the function itself exports. Without having to store them in variables. On this output: createRiver('Amazon', 'South America', 6575)

Comment: tnx. how can i put the objs in Array? Is there a way to do this using the function. So as soon as I enter data, they will move to one big array automatically? And without interrupting the inheritance for the other methods like longerThan and LogRiver.

Comment: `someGlobalArray.push(this);`

Comment: I have tried it. Unfortunately it exports an empty array.

Comment: It works in my code. I don't know what exporting has to do with it, there are no modules here.

Comment: `arrayRiver` needs to be a global variable, not declared inside the function.

Comment: let arrayRiver= [];
arrayRiver.push(this);


createRiver("Amazon","South America",6575);
createRiver("Danube","Europe", 2850);

arrayRiver; //I meant that the objects are not stored in the variable arrayRiver

Comment: `arrayRiver.push(this)` has to be inside the constructor function. If you want to do it outside the function, you use `arrayRiver.push(createRiver(...))`

Comment: `let arrayRiver= [];`   `arrayRiver.push(createRiver()); `   outside of the function `createRiver("Amazon","South America",6575);` `arrayRiver;` somehow the array is still empty

Comment: `createRiver {name: undefined, continent: undefined, lengthInKilometers: undefined}`

Comment: I've updated the answer again to show how to do this.

Comment: You didn't give any arguments to `createRiver()`, that's why all the properties are undefined.

Comment: None of this is specific to objects. This is just ordinary function calling and how to use the results.